# Cursor.forEach in Express hanging when document not found

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using the MongoDB and NodeJS stack trying to do some simple conditional logic. Unfortunately, I am using the MongoDB native driver for NodeJS, and the owner of the project didnt choose to use Mongoose.

The below code is looking through my documents and filtering based on 'props': 'value' and sending a response via Express.

```
 let cursor = db.collection('collection').find({props: 'value' })

 cursor.forEach((doc) => {

      if (!doc) {
          return res.send('No document found with that property assigned!')
      }

      res.json(doc)
 })
```

The method is working fine when the property is found, but Express hangs when the the value isn't found. Does anyone have any fixes?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `No document found ...` condition will never be triggered. The `if` block is inside a section of code that will only be executed if the `doc` variable exists.

Try having the 'no results' condition be a default condition, or check for the cursor to contain documents.